# What does the format from json into a list?

Tags: java, json, arraylist

So basically I'm trying to remove some part of my list, but the problem is because I just got into android development, I don't know the format of the list that I got from JSON file.
Here is the code of my method that retrieve it from a JSON file:

```java
public void getCategory (JSONArray jsonArray, List<ModelCategory> Category){
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
        try {
            ModelCategory currentCategory = new ModelCategory();

            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            currentCategory.setCategoryID(jsonObject.getInt("idCategory"));
            currentCategory.setCategoryName(jsonObject.getString("name"));

            Category.add(currentCategory);
            kat1.addAll(Category);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to remove the `idCategory` from the `kat1` list. But I don't know what the list looks like. I've read about `remove()` method from the list, but how do I utilize the method to remove the `idCategory`?
I'm sorry for the unclear title, I'm pretty new to java development.

Comment: Can you show the code where you initialize `kat1`? What result are you expecting to get?

Comment: @fdermishin `public List<ModelKategori> kat1 = new ArrayList<>();` The `ModelKategori` object have 2 attributes: `idCategory`, and `name`. I'm expecting a list that only has `name`, is this answers your question? I'm sorry if it doesn't

Comment: From your comment, it looks like you actually need a list of strings where the string is name of the modelKategori objects. Why not create a list of strings and then add the name of each category directly to it?